# C++ IDE with Friendlier Error Messages

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I currently use VS 2010 Express for my C++ IDE needs, but have found that its error messages are way too complicated and hard to understand.

Does anyone know of a friendlier windows-compatible C++ IDE with easy-to-understand error messages?

Comment: C++ error messages are always way more complicated, for example, compared to Java or C#.

Comment: I suppose, but I have heard from C++ experts that VS is especially bad at error reporting, though I didn't bother to ask what they thought was a better alternative.

Comment: IMHO Visual C++ is better than GCC-based IDEs :) Maybe Clang is better, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly error messages in C++ are just plain bad there is little they can do about it especially without concepts in the languages. (Although not expanding typedef would certainly help)

Next it isn't IDE that is responsible for the error messages but the compiler. Unfortunately for C++ on windows you really don't have many options without using miniGW or similar.

You can use the Intel compiler with the non commercial license for free (or pay for the commercial version). I have found it's error message but be 'basic' (as in vague) but that is often better than being overwhelmed.

The Intel compiler can be used with Visual Studio IDE.

MiniGW provides a unix like environment for windows this allows you to use gcc and clang. GCC errors are quite similar in complexity to MSVC. Clang however has made the most progress. However you are on your own for getting these to work with an IDE. Although you should be able to get it to work with Eclipse CDT.

Answer (score 0):

Error messages are defined in C standard, and IDEs just parse through the compiler output and show the error message. I don't think changing the IDE makes a difference in error messages.

Comment: Well, if I can't change the error messages, where can I find the standard which defines what the error messages mean. One of my biggest issues with programming in C++ is understanding the error messages.

Comment: you can google the error message and usually you should be able to find a complete explanation with an example to reproduce the error.